# Is it Possible to Merge Rows in SQL from Just One Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataframe, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I wonder if it is possible to merge multiple rows from just one column in SQL. Here's an example of my initial table:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
______________________________

DAVID    | 10.000   | Client 1
DAVID    | 5.000    | Client 2
DAVID    | 12.000   | Client 3
ANDREW   | 2.000    | Client 4
ANDREW   | 3.000    | Client 5
```

Here's my expected output:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
______________________________

DAVID    | 10.000   | Client 1
         | 5.000    | Client 2
         | 12.000   | Client 3
ANDREW   | 2.000    | Client 4
         | 3.000    | Client 5
```

I do not know if it's possible to have a table like the later one. So, any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also please show your research and attempt.

Comment: Thank you, I won't use capitals and as for my attempt I cannot show the code as it has very private and sensitive information.

Comment: FYI, for future reference, you don't need to show us private/sensitive information, you create a [mre], i.e. an example which solves the same problem without revealing anything private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of task is usually done in the presentation layer of the application rather than in the database.

But it can be done in SQL - provided that you have a column that defines the ordering of the rows! Say: `id`.

```
select
    case when row_number() over(partition by col1 order by id) = 1 then col1 end as col1,
    col2,
    col3
from mytable
order by col1, id
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when we show the report in excel, it will be shown this way. But, if you want to see this kind of report in SQL Server, you can use LAG function and then get data accordingly.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(col1 varchar(20), col2 DECIMAL(5,3), col3 varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @table
values
('DAVID', 10.000   ,'Client 1'),
('DAVID', 5.000    ,'Client 2'),
('DAVID', 12.000   ,'Client 3'),
('ANDREW', 2.000   ,'Client 4'),
('ANDREW', 3.000   ,'Client 5');

--SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = prev then '' ELSE col1 END, col2, col3
select case when prev is null then col1
            when prev <> col1 then col1 
            when prev = col1 then ''
            end as col1, col2, col3

from
(
SELECT col1,lag(COL1,1) over(order by col1) as prev, col2, col3
FROM @TABLE
) as t
```

```
+--------+--------+----------+
|  col1  |  col2  |   col3   |
+--------+--------+----------+
| ANDREW |  2.000 | Client 4 |
|        |  3.000 | Client 5 |
| DAVID  | 10.000 | Client 1 |
|        |  5.000 | Client 2 |
|        | 12.000 | Client 3 |
+--------+--------+----------+
```